# Why is the neural network not learning the curve?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For the experimental purpose, I use tf.keras to build a neural network with one neuron attached to sigmoid. The target curve to learn is:

```
#target function
f = lambda x:  - 1./(np.exp(10.*x)+1.)
```

I sampled a few points from the curve for training data.

```
#creat training data

x_train = np.linspace(-1, 1, 111)
y_train = f(x_train)


#test data

x_test = np.linspace(-1, 1, 11)
y_test = f(x_test)
```

The model is as below:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(1,), use_bias=True)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['MeanAbsoluteError'])
```

But it does not learn the curve. Test code is

```
x_test = np.linspace(-1, 1, 11)
plt.plot(x_test, f(x_test), label='true')
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
plt.plot(x_test, y_pred, label='predict')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The code is shared by colab, see

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LQ9MXjrMxsImc80o6wMk1oKfeadnNaG3

There shall be obvious mistake, anybody can help?

Comment: Please include your code, and any outputs, in the question; not as a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sigmoid` activation function can only output values between 0 and 1. Since all the values of `f(x)` are negative, the function cannot be learned.

One way to handle this is to simply normalize the values to `[0, 1]`. In your case, simply learning `f = lambda x: 1./(np.exp(10.*x)+1.)` works fine.